# NPM: edit es6 written plugin in node_modules dir without transpiling

Tags: node.js, webpack

I've got a plugin I wrote in es6, and I'm currently testing the plugin on a site that I'm building. 
When there's an issue, I would like to quickly modify the plugin directly in the node_modules folder, however everytime I need to make a change, I need to rebuild the dist folder for that plugin using babel-cli.

Is there anyway to get around this? Is there a webpack solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understand you correctly where do you execute this code, but any way if it is executed in node - node supports es, just use latest version. If it is browser - then again you have two options execute file without transcompiling it at all https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/, or use babel directly in the browser: http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem derives from the use of a transpiler to transform your source code before loading it into the browser. You can avoid this by using an isomorphic module pattern like [this example](https://github.com/isysd-mirror/iso-module-boilerplate), with introductory [article](https://medium.com/@iravagecoins/isomorphic-es6-node-js-module-boilerplate-w-universal-testing-bb962f02670d).

Another alternative that is webpack compatible is to use the webpack hot loader.